# MYSQL: Returning multiple counts from multiple tables without joining

Tags: mysql

`accounts` table has `account_id`, `account_type`, `date_opened`.

`loans` table has `account_id`, `balance`.

to select the number of new loans:

```
select count(a.account_id) from account a
    where a.date_opened > LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    and a.account_type = 'L'
```

to select the number of open loans:

```
select count(*) from loans l 
    where l.balance > 0
```

or

```
SUM(CASE WHEN l.balance > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as loans_opened
```

How to do this in a single select? Things I've tried:

```
select 
    count(a.account_id),
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.balance > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as loans_opened
    from account a as new_loans,
    LEFT JOIN loans l ON l.account_id = a.account_id
    where a.date_opened > LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and a.account_type = 'L'
```

returns 0 loans

```
select 
    count(a.account_id) as new_loans,
    count(l.account_id) as loans_opened
    from account a as new_loans,
    LEFT JOIN loans l ON l.account_id IN (SELECT account_id from account) and balance > 0
    where a.date_opened > LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and a.account_type = 'L'
```

query never returns

Is there a way to do this with or without joins?

Comment: The result could easily be returned with a single statement, but the statement would have multiple SELECT keywords.  But given the requirement "*to do this in a single select*", the only way to do that is with an ugly cross join (which will only work if both tables are guaranteed to be non-empty) and conditional aggregation. What is the reason for the requirement of using only a single SELECT keyword?

Comment: Ok let me rephrase the question. Can this be done in a single SELECT statement which may contain sub-queries including additional SELECT phrases?

Comment: a SELECT query that returns a scalar (i.e. a single value, the result set is a single row with a single column) ... that subquery can be incorporated into the SELECT list of an outer query.  As a simple demonstration of the pattern:  `SELECT (SELECT 1) AS c1, (SELECT 2) AS c2`.  That pattern can be extended with more complex subqueries e.g.    `SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... ) AS c1, ( SELECT SUM( IF(l.balance > 0, 1, 0) ) FROM ... l ) AS c2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the two `SELECT` queries as subqueries in the main query's `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM account
        WHERE date_opened > LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND account_type = 'L') AS new_loans,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM loans
        WHERE balance > 0) AS open_loans;
```

Comment: Here is a test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/whouqAd8RGtDaCoRF7HtBt/7

I tryed a solution with LEFT JOIN, but your solution have better results :D

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this?

```
select (select count(*) from loans l where l.balance > 0) loans_opened,(select count(a.account_id) from account a where a.date_opened > LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and a.account_type = 'L') new_loans;
```